# useEffect() hook problem ,array based on fetch api is not populated

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern

```js
function RecipesList() {
  //use effect to
  useEffect(() => {
    const getRecipesList = async () => {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/recipe/allrecipes", {
        method: "GET",
      });
      const json = await response.json();

      if (response.ok) {
        setData(json);
        const allCategories = [
          "all",
          ...new Set(data.map((item) => item.category)),
        ];
        setCategories(allCategories);
      }
    };

    getRecipesList();
    //get all categories from data
  }, []);
}
```

Want to populate categories array base on data array

Data array is populated from databse

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a couple of issues if this is the complete code. You need to define the states for categories and data, eg:
`const [data, setData] = useState();`
and
`const [categories, setCategories] = useState();` at the top of the function.

Also, you are trying to use `data.map` immediately after `setData(json)`. Because of the way that React schedules state updates, data will not have the json content until after the component has rerendered.

I think there's two solutions here.

1. Change allCategories so that the array comes from the json variable:

```
const allCategories = ['all', ...new Set(json.map(item => item.category))]
```

or

2. Create a useEffect with `data` in the dependency array and only update the categories state when data changes:

```
 useEffect(() => {
   if (data) {
     setCategories(['all', ...new Set(data.map(item => item.category))]);
   }
 }, [data])
```